# Erro convertendo tipo String em Inteiro no NodeJS

Tags: javascript, cast

em Nodejs estou tentando fazer a verificação do valor de uma variável do tipo String, mas por alguma razão nada está funcionando. Exemplo:

```
var aaa = "0";  // Eu recebo essa variável como string (não dá para mudar o tipo)

console.log(typeof(aaa));   // String
console.log(Number(aaa));   // NaN   ===> Não deveria ser número 0?
console.log(parseInt(aaa)); // NaN   ===> Não deveria ser número 0?

// Isso sempre dá FALSE
aaa = "1";
if (aaa)
    console.log('true');
else
    console.log('false');

// Isso sempre dá FALSE também
aaa = "1";
if (Number(aaa))
    console.log('true');
else
    console.log('false');
```

No que estou errando?

CÓDIGO REAL:

```
  <head>
    <title>TESTE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect();

        function changeState(state) {
            if (state == 1) {
                socket.emit('changeState', '{"state":1}');
                document.getElementById("outputStatus").innerHTML = "Status: ON";
            } else {
                socket.emit('changeState', '{"state":0}');
                document.getElementById("outputStatus").innerHTML = "Status: OFF";
            }
        }


        socket.on('sensorsUpdate', function (data) {
            var reading = JSON.parse(data);
            document.getElementById("IO_opened").innerHTML = reading.IO_opened;
            document.getElementById("IO_closed").innerHTML = reading.IO_closed;

            if (reading.IO_opened) {
                console.log('ABRIR');
                document.getElementById("IO_opened").className = "exibe";
                document.getElementById("IO_closed").className = "n_exibe";
            } else if (reading.IO_closed) {
                console.log('FECHAR');
                document.getElementById("IO_opened").className = "n_exibe";
                document.getElementById("IO_closed").className = "exibe";
            } else {
                console.log('Open = ' + reading.IO_opened + ' Close = ' + reading.IO_closed);
                document.getElementById("IO_opened").className = "n_exibe";
                document.getElementById("IO_closed").className = "n_exibe";
            }
        });
    </script>
  </head>
```

Não entra nunca nesses "if (reading.IO_". Só entra no último "else".
Este código javascript é escrito num arquivo separado é inserido diretamente na página através de um view feita em PUG/Jade, por meio de um include:

```
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js') 
    include ../public/javascripts/sensorStatus.js   //<<<<<====== Include do javascript
  body
```

Comment: Você está executando o código como? Eu testei aqui e nada do que você disse que está acontecendo aconteceu. Veja: https://repl.it/JdOc/0

Comment: Pois é... simulando eu também consegui obter o mesmo resultado que você. Deixa eu dar mais detalhes: o que ocorre é que eu monto meu javascript em NodeJS e publico este código javascript numa View feita com PUG/Jade. Até aí tudo bem, considerando que o código chega idêntico na página que irá executar. Só que ao tratar a tal variável do tipo string conforme mostrei, não apresenta os mesmos resultados. É como se as funções Number() e parseInt() interpretassem valores inválidos...

Comment: Como assim publica o código JS na view? Tem como acrescentar isso na pergunta (o código final gerado)?

Comment: Esse é o código real que está dando problema?

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o resultado de `console.log(typeof aaa, aaa.length, aaa);`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editei o texto da questão para responder sua pergunta. Sergio o log do que você pediu aparece no código real dessa forma: TypeOF IO_opened = string TypeOF IO_closed = string.

Comment: Faltou um `)` no último `if`.

Comment: Já corrigi... acrescentando também uma informação do código real que o @Sergio pediu: Number(reading.IO_closed) = NaN Number(reading.IO_closed) = NaN

Comment: "já corrigi" a que me refiro é que acrescentei ")". Mas o código continua com problema que não sei qual é...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já descobri onde estava o erro.

```
// Eu estava fazendo isso ERRADO!!
var j = {
    "IO_opened": '"' + ioOp + '"',
    "IO_closed": '"' + ioCl + '"'
}

// CORRIGIDO: Agora funciona
var j = {
    "IO_opened": ioOp,
    "IO_closed": ioCl
}

// Esses valores são enviados para a página dessa forma e o JS trata por meio dos "ifs".
s.emit("sensorsUpdate", JSON.stringify(j));
```

Do primeiro jeito eu estava fazendo errado e em lugar de `IO_opened/IO_closed` receberem `"0"` ou `"1"`, eles recebiam `""0""` ou `""1""`, com duas aspas, o que resultava em `Number(IO_opened) = NaN` na conversão lá no JS.

Esse JSON estava em um outro arquivo.... 
É muita informação para um iniciante em Nodejs e JS... estou muito preso ao padrão de outras linguagens. 
Obrigado a todos!